# Create a data frame in r that grows X percentage until hitting a target

Tags: r

Hi am trying to crate a data frame with 2 columns like this

```
Percentage    Value
  100%         100
  110%         110
  120%         120
  130%         130
  150%         150
```

the user will input 3 variables, the starting value in this case 100, the percentage growth, in this case 10% and then when to stop, that would be the target value in this case 150 (it doesn't have to stop exactly in than value, it can be when the value is greater than the target value).  Anybody can help me on how to do this?

You can see that the number of rows in the data frame will vary depending on the user input.

Comment: Have you looked at `?seq` and `?data.frame`?

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
make_my_df <- function(starting = 100, growth = 10, stop = 150) {
  data.frame(Value = seq(from = starting,
                         to   = stop,
                         by   = growth))
}

make_my_df()  # Using defaults; enter other parameters as needed
#>   Value
#> 1   100
#> 2   110
#> 3   120
#> 4   130
#> 5   140
#> 6   150
```